# What files should I prepare to make commutative diagrams in TeX Writer?

Tags: graphics, diagrams, xy-pic, ipad

I am using an iPad app TeX Writer and would like to draw a commutative diagram. I can use `amscd` in the app but it is not sufficient for the diagrams I want to draw.

To include new package, I need to prepare a folder `texmf-local` in which I create a folder `TeXinput` and Zip it. `TeXinput` is a flat directory, no sub directories allowed. It holds everything except for font files. ([Full details here](http://www.texwriterapp.com/install.html))

I tried to add `xy` package but it did not work for me. I'm not sure if I prepared right.

Could you tell me how to prepare the flat directory file so that I can add some diagram packages? Like, which files I should include in the folder `TeXinput`.

It is ok if the package is not `xy` but any other package is acceptable if I can draw commutative diagrams with diagonal lines etc.

Comment: A good package in my opinion is `tikz-cd`. But I don't know how to install it on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work a round for the `xy` package that worked for me if you use DropBox with TeX Writer.

1. Make sure the option sync `texmf-local` is set to on. Create the folder hierarchy in TeX Writer.

   - texmf-local

     - TeXfonts
     - TeXinput
     - TrueType
2. From a computer linked with your dropbox account UnZip the `xypic` package which can be obtained from CTAN.
3. Copy the files from the UnZip folder texinputs into your DropBox folder TeXinput.
   Similarly Copy the files from the UnZip folder texFonts into your DropBox folder TeXfonts.